# Displaying multi selects with advanced custom fields

Tags: arrays, null, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display multiple options with a multi-select option using advanced custom fields. Thanks for any help given.

````
                          $leadType = get_field( 'lead_type' );

                          // Create a comma-separated list from selected values.
                          if(  $leadType ): ?>
                          <p><?php echo implode($leadType,"," ); ?></p>
                          <?php endif; ?> ```
````